# Ruby map to a hash with Hashie::Mash objects

Tags: ruby, object, dictionary, hash

I am trying to filter through an array of mashes(pseudo-objects using the Hashie::Mash gem) containing pages with parent_id's and self_id's. In this function I would like to create a new hash where I can index the children objects by the parent objects.

Here's what I'm trying:

(A parent object has a `parent_id` equal to zero.)
('hashies' is an array containing Hashie::Mash objects that have the page_id attributes)

```
page_hash = Hash[hashies.map { |page|
  if page.parent_id != "0" then [page.id, page] else [page.parent_id, page] end
}]
```

My desired output would be something as follows:

```
page_hash = {
  #<Hashie::Mash id="978835" parent_id="0"> => [
    #<Hashie::Mash id="980705" parent_id="978835">,
    #<Hashie::Mash id="1049260" parent_id="978835">
  ]
}
```

But instead, it seems I'm just altering the Hashie::Mash objects themselves, and changing their parent_id's and id's. Here's my actual output:

```
page_hash = {
  #<Hashie::Mash id="1049100" parent_id="1044858"> => 
    #<Hashie::Mash id="1049100" parent_id="1044858">
}
```

Comment: From the information you've provided, I don't see how you the id's would be changed by the creation of the hash.  Can you provide a simplified example that provides all the code? You haven't included a tag for `"Hashie:Mash"`. Is that your own naming, a gem or what? Also, please reformat to avoid the need for horizontal scrolling. For example, you could write `Hash[hashies.map do |page|; if page.parent_id != "0"; [page.id, page]; else; [page.parent_id, page]; end; end]`, the semicolons indicating the end of each line. The output lines can be broken after `=>`.

Comment: I've noted the formatting work, I'll keep that in mind for future submissions. Thanks for your patience. Also, I was not able to add the "Hashie:Mash" gem as a tag. Thanks for bearing with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
by_id = hashies.group_by(&:id)
page_hash = hashies.group_by { |page| by_id[page.parent_id] }
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, this appears it may have done the trick. I'm going to filter through my output and I'll accept your answer once I've confirmed.